# How to change image into thumbnail in MeteorJS with collectionfs

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, collectionfs, atmosphere.js

Using one of the comments/answers I fixed the photo viewing, however it does not load sometimes if the image is too big. It would be great to see an example of code to turn an image into a thumbnail.

```
<template name="photos">
    <form>
        <input id="file" type="file">
        <input id="addFile" type="submit">
    </form>

    {{#each images}}
      <div>
         <a href="{{this.url}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{this.url store='images' uploading='/images/uploading.jpg' storing='/images/storing.jpg'}}" alt="" class="thumbnail" /></a>
      </div>
    {{/each}}

</template>
```

Javascript:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // Create server database for listings
  var Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
  });

    Template.photos.events({
      'click #addFile' : function(e, t){
        var file = t.find('#file').files[0];
        var ticket = this._id;
        var newFile = new FS.File(file);
        newFile.metadata = {
          ticketId: ticket
        };
        Images.insert(newFile, function (err, fileObj) {
          if (!err) {
            console.log(fileObj);
          }
        });
       }
    });

    Template.photos.helpers({
      images: function () {
        return Images.find(); // Where Images is an FS.Collection instance
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you create publish/subscribe for images collection? 
also i can see that you are using a different store for showing images it should be `<img src="{{this.url  store='images'}}"/>`

Comment: I tried changing source to store='images' with no success, I also removed everything in the src ={{}} except for {{this.url store='images'}}, also no success. Where the image is supposed to be, there is just a picture icon not the actual picture I uploaded. I am not sure what you mean by publish/subscribe, is that related to handlers, because I have read somewhere that it might be required.

Comment: I fixed the image src tag based on your comment. Pictures now load, but would like to change to thumbnail. How would you go about this?